# What is the meaning of "constant" in this context?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am currently reading the *Introduction to Algorithms* book and I have a question in regard to analyzing an algorithm:

The computational cost for merge sort is c lg n according to the book and it says that

> We restrict c to be a constant so that the word size does not grow arbirarily (If the word size could grow arbitrarily, we could store huge amounts of data in one word and operate on it all in constant time)

I do not understand the meaning of "constant" here. Could anyone explain clearly what this means?

Comment: A constant is a value that does not depend on the input size. It remains fixed no matter what the input size is.

Answer (score 0):

Computational complexity in the study of algorithms deals with finding function(s) which provide upper and lower bounds for how much time (or space) the algorithm requires.  Recall basic algebra in high school where you learned about the general point-slope formula for a line? That formula, `y = mx + b`, provided two parameters, m (slope), and b (y intercept), which described a line completely.  Those constants (m,b) described where the line lay, and a larger slope meant that the line was steeper.

Algorithmic complexity is just a way to describe the upper (and possibly lower) bounds for how long an algorithm takes to run (and/or how much space is required).  With big-O (and big-Theta) notation, you are finding a function which provides upper (and lower) bounds for the algorithm costs.  The constants are just shifting the curve, not changing the shape of the curve.

Answer (score 0):

> We restrict c to be a constant so that the word size does not grow arbirarily (If the word size could grow arbitrarily, we could store huge amounts of data in one word and operate on it all in constant time)

On a physical computer, there is some maximum size to a machine word. On a 32-bit system, that would be 32 bits, and on a 64-bit system, it's probably 64 bits. Operations on machine words are (usually) assumed to take time O(1) even though they operate on lots of bits at the same time. For example, if you use a bitwise OR or bitwise AND on a machine word, you can think of it as performing 32 or 64 parallel OR or AND operations in a single unit of time.

When trying to build a theoretical model for a computing system, it's necessary to assume an upper bound on the maximum size of a machine word. If you don't do this, then you could claim that you could perform operations like "compute the OR of n values in time O(1)" or "add together two arbitrary-precision numbers in time O(1)," operations that you can't actually do on a real computer. Therefore, there's usually an assumption that the machine word has some maximum size so that if you do want to compute the OR of n values, you can still do so, but you can't do it instantaneously by packing all the values into one machine word and performing a single assembly instruction to get the result.

Hope this helps!